# No meu site está pedindo uma dll que não existe em meu projeto

Tags: c#, rest, asp.net-web-api

Estou tendo esse erro. A questão não é saber como solucionar, mas entender porque dá **ERRO**, se no meu projeto essa *DLL* não existe. Em *localhost* o site sobe normalmente sem essa *Dll*. Só gostaria de entender isso.
[image: inserir a descrição da imagem aqui]

Comment: Vi o meu web.config e não tem esse assembly. Vi os App.config dos projetos Class Library e também não tem. Se eu subo a Dll, me dá outro erro: `Could not load file or assembly 'Microsoft.ApplicationInsights, Version=2.0.0.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=31bf3856ad364e35' or one of its dependencies. The system cannot find the file specified.`

Comment: você esta usando Application Insights ?

Comment: Provavelmente o sistema operacional requer recursos diferentes para localhost e seu site. Não esqueça que os requisitos de segurança e camadas tcp/http são diferentes nestes casos.

Comment: entendi. O meu site sem o serviço, funciona, mas quando chamo o serviço dá o erro. Já subi a Dll e está dando outra dependência agora. Esse post que fiz, foi apenas para entender mesmo o porquê.

Comment: @MarconcilioSouza, eu não me lembro de instalar. Só instalei o Newtonsoft e o HttpClient via NuGet. Ele está pedindo esse assembly(`Application Insights`), mesmo depois de eu ter subido a `Microsoft.AI.Web`

Comment: Da uma olhada aqui https://stackoverflow.com/questions/38846851/could-not-load-file-or-assembly-microsoft-ai-web-or-one-of-its-dependencies-t

Comment: @PauloHDSousa, obrigado. Eu já havia visto esse link e fiz todo o procedimento e continua dando erro. Me parece que é versão, mas eu não sei ver a versão da Dll. Estou brigando com meu provedor.